# how to fetch specific number of rows (6 rows) from database and get average of those values , then output average to an integer

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

i am creating php script to take input from a data base containing [id,value,date] , there are many rows (increasing every minute using an api) .
I want to fetch 6 rows everytime like 1to6 , then perform their average(val1+2+3+4+5+6/6) and store that average into a variable.
This whole process is continuous,
means 1to6->average->outputin variable
then  6to12->average->outputin variable
and like that

i am using php and i did

```
$var=1;
$raw = "SELECT id, value, date FROM db";
$result = $conn->query($raw);

$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

if ($result->num_rows < $var) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    
    echo nl2br("\n");
    echo "price: " . $row["value"];
    echo nl2br("\n");
  }
$var++;
```

please give me solution to my problem, ❤php

Comment: `SELECT AVG(value) FROM (SELECT value FROM db LIMIT 6) t` but this will only fetch 6 records randomly.... you'd have to apply an appropriate WHERE condition for more precise selection (sorry, had to edit it twice)

Comment: Can you provide more code to make your goal more clean? The role of a `$var` is pretty unclean here.

Comment: thank you @HonkderHase your SQL query gave me the idea to get average, i made a query that  eveytime takes 6 new values from db and averages them and outputs the average , here is the result- `SELECT AVG(price) FROM (SELECT price FROM price ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 0, 6) items;`

Answer (score 1):

instead of fetching data from sql to  php script , i averaged the data itself on the sql server using this query

```
SELECT AVG(table) FROM (SELECT table FROM db ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 6) items;
```

Comment: This is the correct soution for my problem, i saved this command as a procedure in my mysql server and this executes everytime a new data is entered , anyway , it gets my work done , thanks